# Can I combine two models in ModelBuilder in ArcGIS?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, modelbuilder

I am using ModleBuilder within AcrGIS and am trying to create a modle that will:

1) Take my polygon layer and create an inverted buffer (using a negative value)
2) Add a field to the new polygon layer
3) Take that polygon layer and turn it into a raster
4) Take the raster and convert it to points
5) Add a field to the points layer
6) Use the spatial join tool to combine the attributes into one layer and table

I have made a model that encompasses all of the tools and analysis, but it has failed to run. It keeps reporting that it cannot complete the rater to point portion of the model. I have tried making two separate tools (one for the buffer, and another tool to create the points), and they ran without any problems. However that requires me to add the inverted polygon to the points model separately. It appears to only be an issue when the two are put together.

Am I doing something wrong, or is there a way for me to combine two separate models into one model?

The first image is the model with all of the components in it. The second image is of just the buffer model, and the third image is of creating the points.

Here is the code for the whole model I have built this far:

```
import arcpy

# Load required toolboxes
arcpy.ImportToolbox("Model Functions")


# Local variables:
B_mdb = "C:\\Users\\Desktop\\temp\\ModelBuilder\\B.mdb"
Name = "B"
B = "C:\\Users\\Desktop\\temp\\ModelBuilder\\B.mdb\\B"
inverted_buff_shp = "C:\\Users\\Desktop\\temp\\ModelBuilder\\inverted_buff.shp"
inverted_buff_shp__2_ = inverted_buff_shp
bark_cells_tif = "C:\\Users\\Desktop\\temp\\ModelBuilder\\bark_cells.tif"
bark_points_shp = "C:\\Users\\Desktop\\temp\\ModelBuilder\\bark_points.shp"
bark_points_shp__2_ = bark_points_shp
inverted_buff_SpatialJoin = "C:\\Users\\Documents\\ArcGIS\\Default.gdb\\inverted_buff_SpatialJoin"

# Process: Iterate Feature Classes
arcpy.IterateFeatureClasses_mb(B_mdb, "", "", "NOT_RECURSIVE")

# Process: Buffer
arcpy.Buffer_analysis(B, inverted_buff_shp, "-0.35 Meters", "FULL", "ROUND", "NONE", "", "PLANAR")

# Process: Add Field (2)
arcpy.AddField_management(inverted_buff_shp, "model", "TEXT", "", "", "", "", "NULLABLE", "NON_REQUIRED", "")

# Process: Polygon to Raster
arcpy.PolygonToRaster_conversion(inverted_buff_shp, "OBJECTID", bark_cells_tif, "CELL_CENTER", "NONE", "2")

# Process: Raster to Point
arcpy.RasterToPoint_conversion(bark_cells_tif, bark_points_shp, "Value")

# Process: Add Field
arcpy.AddField_management(bark_points_shp, "orient", "DOUBLE", "", "", "", "", "NULLABLE", "NON_REQUIRED", "")

# Process: Spatial Join
arcpy.SpatialJoin_analysis(inverted_buff_shp__2_, bark_points_shp__2_, inverted_buff_SpatialJoin, "JOIN_ONE_TO_ONE", "KEEP_ALL", "orient \"orient\" true true false 0 Double 0 0 ,First,#,C:\\Users\\Desktop\\temp\\ModelBuilder\\bark_points.shp,orient,-1,-1;NO_NAME \"NO_NAME\" true true false 19 Double 0 0 ,First,#,C:\\Users\\Desktop\\temp\\ModelBuilder\\inverted_buff.shp,NO_NAME,-1,-1;Shape_Leng \"Shape_Leng\" true true false 19 Double 0 0 ,First,#,C:\\Users\\Desktop\\temp\\ModelBuilder\\inverted_buff.shp,Shape_Leng,-1,-1;Shape_Area \"Shape_Area\" true true false 19 Double 0 0 ,First,#,C:\\Users\\Desktop\\temp\\ModelBuilder\\inverted_buff.shp,Shape_Area,-1,-1;BUFF_DIST \"BUFF_DIST\" true true false 19 Double 0 0 ,First,#,C:\\Users\\Desktop\\temp\\ModelBuilder\\inverted_buff.shp,BUFF_DIST,-1,-1;ORIG_FID \"ORIG_FID\" true true false 10 Long 0 10 ,First,#,C:\\Users\\Desktop\\temp\\ModelBuilder\\inverted_buff.shp,ORIG_FID,-1,-1;model \"model\" true true false 254 Text 0 0 ,First,#,C:\\Users\\Desktop\\temp\\ModelBuilder\\inverted_buff.shp,model,-1,-1", "INTERSECT", "", "")
```

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: can you share the code behind the model by exporting it to python? It would make it easier to help.

Comment: I added the python script, however I hear you cannot use the ArcGIS iterators in python. Is that true?

Comment: That is true, but the iterator doesn't seem to be the issue here.

Comment: When running the model are there any messages on the results pane for geoprocessing? Reviewing the code, everything checks out with how the functions should be setup. I'm wondering if a warning is generated when the full model runs that could give out more facts. If you are not aware of how to add this pane, in ArcMap  go to geoprocessing menu -> click results. Run the model and then expand the sessions for today. Let us know the outcome.

Comment: When I try to run the model it says "not exist within table Failed to execute (Polygon to Raster)". And there were no results in the geoprocessing pane (I checked recent and not completed).

Comment: I think it's because the field code "Value" doesn't exist in the input raster. Can you try leaving it out?

Comment: Changing the filed code "OBJECTID" to "ORIG_FID" allowed the ModelBuilder to compete the polygon to raster step. But if I delete "Value" or replace it with "Count" in the Raster to Point step, the model does not run either. It said" Users\Desktop\... does not have valid statistics as required by the operation."

Comment: It might seem silly, but try "VALUE".

Comment: Changing it to "VALUE" did not work. But changing the Raster to Point's Field to "ORIG_FID" just like the Polygon to Raster's Value Field did not produce an error, however it did not run the whole model, it stopped after the Polygon to Raster conversion.

Comment: How big is the .shp that is being created. Looks like the RASTER to POINT could have a file size limitation. https://support.esri.com/en/technical-article/000007580

Comment: The original .shp file is only 1,071 KB, and the bark_cell.tif (the raster layer I am trying to create) file is only 181.55 MB, and the final points layer is coming out to about 1,000 KB.

Comment: Make sure that .shp file bark_points.shp doesn't exist, and also try this a variation worked locally for me  -   arcpy.RasterToPoint_conversion(r "C:\Users\Desktop\temp\ModelBuilder\bark_cells.tif", r "C:\Users\Desktop\temp\ModelBuilder\bark_points.shp", "VALUE")